# Inject parameters to Angular CLI from AspNetCore

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-cli

I am using aspnet core 2.0 angular cli template. I have added OpenId authentication to it, and then initializing angular app after that.

I need to pass recd claims to my angular app, to identify role and user id.
How do I pass inject these details to angular app ? 
Like: username, user id, role etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create API (e.g. Restful-json) in ASP which login user and after succes returns details like username, id, role etc. And from angular app you post (ajax) request witch user credentials to this API. Below I put example

```
POST http://your-app.com/login
Request Body: { email: 'xx@yy.com', pass: 'secret' }
Request response: { id: 666, username: 'John Smith', role: 'manager'
```

And in angular when you receive response, you have needed data. Of course login function must do backend login things like e.g set proper cookies etc.

This approach also prepare you in future to use so called micro-services architecture where backend and fronted are SEPARATE projects which communicate only by Restful API.

Comment: Can't use this approach. I have added authentication to dotnet core pipeline, and added open id and wsfed both. Based on configuration I am navigating to specific pipeline. Adding API, I won't be able to use that.